# HTML Label widths, want fixed but it keeps auto-sizing according to text?

Tags: html, css

I am creating some tabs using labels, then im going to add some simple hover over javascript. However i want all the labels to be of fixed size with the text in the centre. This is what i have:

```
<style>
        .button
        {
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            background-color:rgb(193,203,225);
            font: normal 14px arial, sans, sans-serif;
            text-align:center;
            color: rgb(54,95,145);
            width:100px;
            margin: 0px; 
            padding: 0px; 
            padding-top: 3px; 
            padding-bottom: 3px; 
            text-align: center; 
        }
    </style>

    <label id='Label5' class='button'>  Personal Details  </label>
    <label id='Label1' class='button'>     Education      </label>
    <label id='Label2' class='button'>    Achievements    </label>
    <label id='Label3' class='button'>   Work Experience  </label>
    <label id='Label6' class='button'>     IT Skills      </label>
    <label id='Label4' class='button'>     Languages      </label>
```

but its not working? Could someone please help?

Comment: If you're using the `<label>` tag, you should use the `for` attribute to link it to the corresponding input. `for` should contain the `id` of the linked input.

Comment: My 2 cents: I think this is not a proper use for a `<label>` tag. `<label>` tags are intended to represent a label for some other element which is why it has the `for` attribute. The defacto standard is to use a `<ul>` with `<li>`s to represent tabs but if you want something simpler than that, just use `<div>` with your .button class so you aren't overloading a tag that has other specialized meaning.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

a layer is a inline-element, and you can't give a `width` to inline-elements. try to set `display:inline-block` for `.button` (note that this [isn't supported](http://www.css4you.de/display.html) by IE6)

Comment: Sadly, IE7 has issues with inline-block

Comment: @Scott Evernden-IE7 has issues if the element normally has `block` display by default

Answer (score 8):

you need to add `display:block` to get widths to work, and then add `float:left` to get them to layout the way you want

Comment: i think ´inline-block´ would be easier in this case

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: inline-block` to the `.button` class as labels are inline elements so it does not recognize your width.

Answer (score 1):

```
label.button {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Why the down votes?  This is correct... The other answers mention using inline-block positioning, but then also point that you can't really use it anyway due to IE.  Using block positioning is the most reliable cross-browser solution.